# MS Access Report Sorting

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a query that returns a list of ID's and dollar amounts.

I want to sort my report that is based on this query by descending dollar amount but I want to put the ID's together. ie,

```
ID   Amount
--  --------
5    $90
3    $88
3    $5
9    $80
```

etc. Is there a way to do this using a Sort by 'expression'?

Thanks!

Comment: If your Amount is Currency type, you can use order by clause to sort your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would I still be able to group the ID's together?

Comment: Yes you can query your ID while sorting by Amount.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. I have an ORDER BY amount clause in my query but I want to keep the ID's together when displayed in the report. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There is no point using order by in a report, the report will use its own order. use Group and Sort for the report itself.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, please see my answer below.

Comment: Whenever I try to use a GROUP on the ID, it forces me to sort by it. I don't want to sort by ID but by Amount :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sorting by the maximum amount per ID, so you need access to that column in your report query:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.amount, 
       (SELECT Max(amount) 
        FROM   test b 
        WHERE  b.id = a.id) AS maxamount 
FROM   test a 
ORDER  BY maxamount DESC, 
          a.amount DESC; 

ID  AMOUNT  MAXAMOUNT
5   90      90
3   88      88
3   5       88
9   80      80
```

Once you have `MAXAMOUNT` in your query you can use it as the report sort criteria.

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
select ID, Amount, ID & ' ' & Amount as ID_Amount_Together From Table ORDER BY Amount Desc;
```

Or if you do not want to concatenate Amount and ID then

```
select ID, Amount From Table ORDER BY Amount Desc;
```

Comment: Don't know much about Access Reports. Maybe time to upgrade to SQL Server & SSRS ;).

Comment: If you do not know how to use a technology it is time to change? :)